# How do I align iframe element that's inside a cell along with other cells inside a html table.?

Tags: html, css, iframe, html-table

How do i align the iframe elements that's inside the table cell along with the rest of the table cells inside the table so that it appears in the same way if it were a td element. ?

I tried to align by adding inline style position:relative; top:-4px to the iframe element.

```html
<iframe src="Static/Pan.htm" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="190" height="30" style="width: 190px;height: 30px; display:table-cell; position:relative; top:-4px"></iframe>
```

I don't think this is the right way. Are there any alternative ways to align it?

Main Html

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>Name
    </td>

    <td>Phone Number
    </td>

    <td>Address
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <iframe src="Address.htm" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="190" height="30" style="width: 190px;height: 30px; display:table-cell;"></iframe>

    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="update" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Iframe Address.htm

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the actual output:
[image: Actual Output]

This is the intended output:
[image: Expected output]

Comment: please post css code also..thanx

Comment: The only css that i have added is for the iframe element and it is in the html code.

Answer (score 0):

Target the desired cells like this :

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This will align the content of your cell to the top of the cell.

Comment: no luck, the cell containing the iframe remains at the same position.